# Julia, handle keyboard interrupt

Tags: sigint, julia

Title says it all. How can I handle or catch a `SIGINT` in julia? From the docs I assumed I just wanted to catch `InterruptException` using a `try/catch` block like the following

```
try
    while true
        println("go go go")
    end
catch ex
    println("caught something")
    if isa(ex, InterruptException)
        println("it was an interrupt")
    end
end
```

But I never enter the catch block when I kill the program with `^C`.

**edit:** The code above works as expected from the julia REPL, just not in a script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see the same behavior as alto, namely that `SIGINT` kills the entire process when my code is run as a script but that it is caught as an error when run in the REPL.  My version is quite up to date and looks rather similar to that of tholy:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.7
Commit cb9bcae* (2015-03-23 21:36 UTC)
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Sandybridge)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

Digging through the source, I found hints that `Julia's` interrupt behavior is determined by an `jl_exit_on_sigint` option, which can be set via a `ccall`.  `jl_exit_on_sigint` is `0` for the REPL, but it looks as if `init.c` sets it to `1` when running a `Julia` program file from the command line.

Adding the appropriate `ccall` makes alto's code works regardless of the calling environment:

```
ccall(:jl_exit_on_sigint, Void, (Cint,), 0)

try
    while true
        println("go go go")
    end
catch ex
    println("caught something")
    if isa(ex, InterruptException)
        println("it was an interrupt")
    end
end
```

This does seem to be a bit of a hack.  Is there a more elegant way of selecting the interrupt behavior of the environment?  The default seems quite sensible, but perhaps there should be a command line option to override it.

Comment: `Void` has been renamed to `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

For julia >= 1.5, there is [`Base.exit_on_sigint`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.exit_on_sigint). From the docs (retrieved on 20220419)

> Set `exit_on_sigint` flag of the julia runtime. If false, Ctrl-C (SIGINT) is capturable as `InterruptException` in try block. This is the default behavior in REPL, any code run via -e and -E and in Julia script run with -i option.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I'm running

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.0-prerelease+695
Commit 47915f3* (2013-12-27 05:27 UTC)
DEBUG build
Platform Info:
  System: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       L 640  @ 2.13GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY)
  LAPACK: libopenblas
  LIBM: libopenlibm
```

but I expect it's not necessary to be fully up-to-date for this to work (I'd guess 0.2 should be fine too).

Comment: I'm on 0.3.0-prerelease+459. After you said it worked I went back and tested again. It works in the REPL, but not if I put the code in a .jl  file and call it like $ julia somefile.jl